# Yii - PHP - How parse subdirectory to a module (and their other params)

Tags: php, yii

**The problem:**
I can't run Yii Application in document root (like http://domain.com)
.htaccess, index.php, nothing in the document root  :blink:

**What's my objective:**
Identify directories as modules in the application, then, redirect to they.

**Example:**

domain.com/site1                  -> yii/modules/Site1Module/DefaultController

domain.com/Site1/subscription     -> yii/modules/Site1Module/SubscriptionController

domain.com/Site2/contact?whatsapp -> yii/modules/Site2Module/ContactController (get whatsapp var)

---

I'm try to bootstrap all in my DefaultController root application:

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $baseUrlModule = substr(Yii::app()->getRequest()->baseUrl, 1);
    $baseRequestUri = substr(Yii::app()->getRequest()->requestUri, 1);

    if(Yii::app()->hasModule($baseUrlModule))
    {
        $this->redirect(array(Yii::app()->getRequest()->requestUri));
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo '404';
    }

}
```

}

Then, in each directory will be copied index.php to Yii::createWebApplication ...

But unfortunately it did not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Yii can do this automatically. All you need is to correctly configure UrlManager component. Here is the link to the  [relevant part of documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url).